# Problems in IE without doctype

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, w3c

I have a specific problem by a fixed bar.
I would to use this fixedbar but I sould n't use doctype
This bar in IE have problems. for example bar by scroll is not fixed and move or size of tooltips changed.
In fact, my project owner don't let me to use of doctype

http://ryan.rawswift.com/sandbox/jixedbar-0.0.2/demo/

Edit:
Hi to all , that is right.
but exceptionally, I must start html file whth "html tag" in this project! 
It is good that you help me to fixed this bar  when scroll change.
Other problems isn't important….

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to IE6 (are you??), then there would be an issue that is possibly related to the use of the css style `position:fixed;` because IE6 does not support this css property.

However, if the author has done this in jQuery, one would expect there to possibly be a fix implemented for this.

Onto the topic of doc types, you say that there is an issue in IE without doc types. Generally there would be a problem in many browsers without declaring a doc type. While many will revert to a default doc type, it is common (and very good) practice to specify your doc type based on your code (HTML, XHTML, HTML 5.0 etc etc).

Kind regards,
Simon

Answer (score 1):

IE8 (maybe 7 as well, forget about 6) behaves **almost** up to standard when you use a STRICT DOCTYPE, so use the *XHTML STRICT DOCTYPE*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Haha, thanks, I've noticed that IE6 somewhat behaves as predicted when using XHTML 1.0 Strict, but I don't bargain on it.

Comment: @Kyle - I saw a classic quote the other day, sure you'll appreciate it: "...and by the 6th day God had created the earth, it was beautiful, immaculate... and then he tested it in IE!" - Unkown

Comment: @webfac: It was a guy on Twitter, who tweeted it almost 10 months ago, but it's still trending. Lol

Comment: @Anriëtte LOL that is brilliant. I may have got the phrase a bit wrong, but you get the idea! Funny how those trends keep going!