# Background not showing in internet explorer when using JQuery load function

Tags: php, jquery, css

I use the following jquery code to load a page...

```
$(function() {
$('#stats').load('statsto.php');

    var visibleInterval = 60000;
    var invisibleInterval = 120000;

    $(function() {
        setTimer();
        $(document).bind('visibilitychange'), function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            setTimer();    
        };
    });

    function displayStats() {
        $('#stats').load('statsto.php');
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    }

    function setTimer() {
        timer = setInterval(displayStats, (document.hidden) ? invisibleInterval : visibleInterval);
    }

});
```

and here is the style from statsto.php...

```
body {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 7px;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url("grad.png");
}
```

But the background image is not showing in internet explorer. I have tried using `background: black url("grad.png");` but that also doesn't work. I have also tried including the style in the same page as the JQuery code, but still no luck.

Comment: grad.png is located in the same directory than the html with #stats? try using the absolute url of the image

Comment: What version of IE, also, how and when are you calling the function displayStats()?

Comment: The image is in the same directory, I have also tried using the full url. The version of Internet Explorer I am using is IE7

Comment: See if adding a DOCTYPE solves things -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013978/problems-in-ie-without-doctype

Comment: As a side note: The line with ajaxSetup should go before the #stats line, otherwise it has no effect. Plus you only need to use that once per page load, so you may want to take it out of the function.

Comment: @b01 The page re-loads every 30 seconds (using `setInterval`, hence the ajaxSetup

Comment: @mblase75 I already have a DOCTYPE on the page

Comment: I have included the full jquery

Comment: Are you using any HTML5 elements in `statsto.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Your issue may be with the `.load()` function itself (in Internet Explorer). I seem to remember encountering an issue with that a while back...

**Try this**

```
$.get('statso.php', function() {
  $('#stats').html();
});
```

Comment: function displayStats() {
  $.get('statsto.php', function() {
     $('#stats').html();
  });
 }